# Is it possible to consume http response with "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;" with retrofit or okhttp

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp

Actually I'm trying to get audio that is streamed via http with such response:

> ```
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
> Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
> Connection: close
> Content-Type: multipart/mixed;boundary=audioframe
>
> --audioframe
> Content-Type: audio/L16;rate=8000;channels=1
> Content-Length: 640
> X-Time: 2014-07-02T18:40:31.639+04:00
> ...<binary data>...
> --audioframe
> Content-Type: audio/L16;rate=8000;channels=1
> Content-Length: 640
> X-Time: 2014-07-02T18:40:31.639+04:00
> ...<binary data>...
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I've found that @Streaming can't be used with RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL 
That was the issue!

https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/561